# MySQL for EXCEL (2010) - Custom select query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, mysql, vba, mysql-workbench

I have the **MySQL for Excel** (MS E:2010) addin enabled (most current version).
I've tested my connection to my server (non-local), and all is great, however I can't see anywhere to write / insert a custom SQL Select Query to pull data from different tables, rather than just 1 table.

Is this not possible?

2 further options:
1)  I have been able to use the database connector & add my server, (through the ODBC wizard), however I keep getting syntax errors, and I have no idea why as my syntax works perfectly in MySQL Workbench (I have tried with both ANSI & Unicode options).

2)  Run a `VBA` macro to trigger a `.bat` file which will launch my `.sql script` in MySQL Workbench, to run the Query, and save to the harddrive in .csv or .txt

3)  (I've since got part to work today), have a VBA macro run with MS Power Query, the report is spot on, however it won't record the macro for automation.  :(

These are my 3(4) options and each one is not working.  Which is the best fit?

Cheers.

Here is a sample of my `SELECT` query:

```
USE `store_cart`;
    Select  
        T5.orders_id As OID,
        DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, '%Y-%m-%d') As ODate,
        T3.products_name As PName,
        T3.products_id As PID,
        T2.products_quantity As Qty,
        T2.products_price As PrOrig,
        T5.currency As Cur,
        "1" As CurVal,
        (select PrOrig) * (select CurVal) as PrBase,
    From /*PREFIX*/products T1
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
        Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
        Inner Join /*PREFIX*/products_description T3 On (T1.products_id = T3.products_id)
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/products_to_categories P2 On (T3.products_id = P2.products_id)
        Inner Join /*PREFIX*/customers T6 On T5.customers_id = T6.customers_id
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/paypal P1 On (P1.order_id = T5.orders_id)
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/group_pricing g1 On T6.customers_group_pricing = g1.group_id    
        Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_status O1 On (O1.orders_status_id = T5.orders_status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation of MySQL for Excel, startup Excel, go to the "Data" ribbon and on the right you should see a "MySQL for Excel" button. That should be the best (and preferred) way to connect to a MySQL database, using MySQL for Excel.

[image: MySQL for Excel]

If you need to aggregate data from different tables, the best place to do that is in the database. Create a view there (MySQL has a Workbench that lets you do such things quite intuitively) and use that view as a basis for your Excel report. The advantage is that everyone now has access to that aggregated data. Also: databases are optimized to do things as aggregating data.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want to use, however I can't run my custom query that pulls data from more than 1 table.  I don't want to have to import 5 tables to then join them in excel itself.  Is there no way to get MySQL for Excel to run a multi-table custom query?  I don't think there is. :(

Comment: The most logic solution would be to create a view in the database you are using.

Comment: Which unfortunately begs the question ..  how, or at least where?  Thank you in advance :D  [edit] I have found info on the how, but where is the best place? on my server?  this is out of my league I think :(

Comment: That is my question though - how do I do what I need to do, you're answer already tells me what I already know - my question is how to implement it, which is what I've just asked.  :(

Comment: Do you have access to the sql server en are you allowed to create a view in the database?

Comment: Thanks for your direction, I found how to do it in MySQL Workbench & have been able to see the `view` in Excel, I'm hitting errors now though, `System.Byte[]`, I can start a new question for that though. I know why the error is there (it's a calculation based column), I don't know how to fix it.  If you edit your answer I'll mark it as answered & write my next question, thank you :)

Comment: Great that you are (partly) there. I appended a parapgraph about creating a view and MySQL workbench. Sorry if I was a bit blunt in my previous (now deleted) comments.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I appreciate your help. Thank you & no apologies needed. :)